# Impossible to create a yo meanjs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mean

I am trying to begin this online tutorial:
http://www.bradoncode.com/tutorials/mean-stack-tutorial-part-1-setup/

Everything seems to be installed and ready, but when asked to 'yo meanjs', I got this error msg:

[image: my error message]

Have I done something wrong?

Comment: "my error message" - sounds like your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think its just need sudo. I see yo is not able to create dir for express.

Try:

```
sudo yo meanjs
```

Comment: I tried it when i saw 'please try running as root', but when I do this, I get the same message..

Comment: OK, I googled on the first error line `ERR! Darwin 14.5.0`. I had an hunch that this error could be due to the fact that your node version is old and does not match with npm version.

Open this [Github link](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7555) and press `CTRL/CMD + f` and search "othiym23 commented on Aug 18", for details hon how to fix this.

**Please NOTE:** Careful with upgrades. For me once after upgrading node, I had to re-install node and npm to fix some package related issue

Comment: Thanks Vijay, I thought it would work, but at the last second I got the same message "
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, symlink '../swig/bin/swig.js'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, symlink '../swig/bin/swig.js'] errno: -13, code: 'EACCES', path: '../swig/bin/swig.js' }" I tried to google it and stuff but nothing new..

Comment: Ok I had to reinstall everything, from node to yo, but it looks like it's working now ! Thank you very much !

Comment: Hmm I think it was probably due to old n preleased node version (0.x.x)